# How do I check if a string matching regex already exists in array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, scripting, duplicates

I am trying to create array of non duplicate line going from end of array to start from another array.

I tried this:

```
for(var i = len; i > 0; i--){
        if(resultArray[i] != undefined && resultArray[i].match(blahRegex)){
            if(lastArray[blahRegex]){
                console.log("entering here")
                lastArray.push(resultArray[i])
            }
            // console.log(resultArray[i])
        }
```

Comment: We need *input* and expected *output* ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` for that.

Here is an example:

```
var lastArray = resultArray.filter(value => blahRegex.test(value));
```

Oh, just noticed that you want to keep only unique values.

```
var lastArray = resultArray.reduce((acc, value) => {
     if(blahRegex.test(value) && acc.indexOf(value) == -1){
         acc.push(value);
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
```

What this does is to retain all unique values in the `resultArray` array that match the `blahRegex` regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `filter` and `Set`:

```
let lastArray = [...new Set(resultArray.filter(value => blahRegex.test(value)))];
```